# Button does not render correctly when drawn with Graphics2D

Tags: java, awt

I am coding a button for a UI I am creating myself, to use in an RPG game's menu.
The button is supposed to turn red whenever the mouse is hovering over the button, and the mouse is pressed down.

The button occasionally flashes red, but most of the time remains green.
The color `c1` is green, and the color `c2` is red. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I have this in my `PushButton` code:

```java
package rpg.menu;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import rpg.main.CatHero;

public class PushButton extends Button {
  public boolean hovering;
  public boolean isMouseDown;
  public PushButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, String message, int id,
      Color c1, Color c2) {
    super(x, y, width, height, message, id, c1, c2, true);
  }
  public void tick() {
    isMouseDown = CatHero.getCatHero().in.mouseDown;
    Point p = new Point(
        CatHero.getCatHero().in.mouseX, CatHero.getCatHero().in.mouseY);
    if (contains(p)) {
      hovering = true;
    } else if (!contains(p)) {
      hovering = false;
    }

    if (isMouseDown && hovering) {
      press();
    }
    CatHero.getCatHero().in.mouseDown = false;
  }
  public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    if (isMouseDown && hovering) {
      g.setColor(c2); // Red when pressed
    } else {
      g.setColor(c1); // Green when not pressed or released
    }

    g.fill(this);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (width / 5)));
    g.drawString(message, x, y + (height / 2));
  }
}
```

and this is my `InputHandler` code:

```java
package rpg.io;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class InputHandler implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    public boolean[] key = new boolean[68836];
    public boolean mouseDown = false;
    public int mouseX;
    public int mouseY;
    public boolean allowKeyboardInput = true;
    public boolean allowMouseInput = true;

    public InputHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // Handle mouse click if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (allowMouseInput) {
            mouseDown = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (allowMouseInput) {
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // Handle mouse enter if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // Handle mouse exit if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Handle key typed if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (allowKeyboardInput) {
            key[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (allowKeyboardInput) {
            key[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // Handle mouse dragging if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if (allowMouseInput) {
            mouseX = e.getX();
            mouseY = e.getY();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also done this in my main file:

```java
addKeyListener(in);
addMouseListener(in);
addMouseMotionListener(in);
```

Here is the Button Class Code:

```
package rpg.menu;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import rpg.main.CatHero;

public class Button extends Rectangle{
public boolean isEnabled;
public String message;
public int id;
public Color c1;
public Color c2;
    public Button(int x, int y, int width, int height, String message, int id, Color c1, Color c2, boolean startAs) {
    super(x,y,width,height);
    this.message = message;
    this.id = id;
    isEnabled = startAs;
    this.c1 = c1;
    this.c2 = c2;
    }
    public void press() {
        CatHero.getCatHero().handleButton(id);
    }
    public void toggle() {
    isEnabled = !isEnabled;
    }
    public boolean touches(Rectangle r) {
        return r.intersects(this);
    }
}
```

Main file code:

```
package rpg.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import rpg.game.saveload.Settings;
import rpg.io.InputHandler;
import rpg.menu.PushButton;
import rpg.menu.ToggleButton;

public class CatHero extends Canvas implements Runnable {
public Thread thread;
public boolean isRunning = false;
public Graphics2D g;
public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 1920;
public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 1080;
public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT_TILE = 18;
public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH_TILE = 60;
public static CatHero game;
public InputHandler in;
public ToggleButton tb;
public PushButton pb;
public int gameDiffuculty;
public int gameState;
public boolean allowPause;
public Settings sett;
    public CatHero() {
        tb = new ToggleButton(0,0,50,50,"test",0,true,Color.GREEN,Color.RED);
         in = new InputHandler();
         pb = new PushButton(0,50,50,50,"say hello",1, Color.GREEN,Color.RED);
         sett = new Settings();
        addKeyListener(in);
        addMouseListener(in);
        addMouseMotionListener(in);
        in.allowKeyboardInput = true;
        in.allowMouseInput = true;
        allowPause = true;
        gameState = 0;
        /*
         * 0: menu
         * 1: game
         * 2: paused
         * 3: battle
         * 4: inventory
         */
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            tick();
            render();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    private void start() {
        if(isRunning)
            return;
        isRunning = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    private void stop() {
        if(!isRunning)
            return;
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public void tick() {
    tb.tick();
    pb.tick();
    }
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        return;
    }
    g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    tb.render(g);
    pb.render(g);
g.dispose();
bs.show();
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
     game = new CatHero();
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cat Hero");
     frame.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH,CANVAS_HEIGHT);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.add(game);
     game.start();
}
public void handleButton(int id) {
    if(id == 0) {
        sett.testDiffuculty = tb.isEnabled;
    }
    if(id == 1) {
        System.out.println(sett.testDiffuculty);
    }
}
public void loadSettings(Settings s) {
    
    
}
public static CatHero getCatHero() {
    return game;    
}
public void cutsceneModeToggle() {
in.allowMouseInput = !in.allowMouseInput;
in.allowKeyboardInput = !in.allowKeyboardInput;
}
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It appears PushButton extends Button.  Is that java.awt.Button, or an internal Button class which you have not shown us?

Comment: @VGR I can't fit the code but I do have it

Comment: PushButton defines a `public void render(Graphics2D g)` method, but I don’t see any code which calls that method.

Comment: @VGR I have added the code for that as well.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1)` sleeps for one millisecond.  You are trying to redraw your button *one thousand times per second.*  It’s not a surprise that the painting system is choking on that.  Choose a more reasonable frame rate.  For example, if you want to redraw the button eight times per second, use `Thread.sleep(1000 / 8)`.